# Determining the number of MySQL rows to DELETE to reach a target database size

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, innodb

I have a database with 3 tables (A, B, C) that I need keep below a certain threshold size.

A has a 1-to-many relation with B and C...

Specifically, A, B, and C have a col called 'g_id' that is used to establish a relation with each other.. Kind of like a graph structure where A, B, and C are graphs, nodes, and edges, respectively.

My goal is: Every day, a script will get the size of this database and delete rows from these three tables until the total size of the database has shrunk back down to a target size.

I attempted the following:

1. Fetch the size of the database with

   ```
    SELECT
        TABLE_NAME,
        round(((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024), 2) as SIZE_MB
         FROM
             information_schema.TABLES
         WHERE
             TABLE_NAME in ('A', 'B', 'C') AND
             TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
         ORDER BY
             SIZE_MB DESC
   ```
2. Attempt to estimate the sizes of each logical grouping of (A, B, C) with respect to their g_ids...

   ```
   SELECT
       g_id,
       SUM(length(col1)) + SUM(constant) as total
   FROM (
       (SELECT A.g_id, A.col1, 22 as constant FROM A) UNION ALL
       (SELECT B.g_id, B.col1, 22 as constant FROM B) UNION ALL
       (SELECT C.g_id, C.col1, 22 as constant FROM C) UNION ALL
      ) ABC
   GROUP BY g_id
   ORDER BY g_id;
   ```

where the 22 constant is just a rough estimate of the cost of storing some fixed bigints, timestamps, etc per row... and col1 is a text field with variable length.

3. After loading part 2 in memory, loop through the selected rows and programmatically add g_ids to a list until just enough rows have been selected for deletion to bring the database back to a desired size.
4. Finally execute DELETE WHERE g_id IN ({g_ids}) for tables A, B, C...

The problem is that the size returned from part 1 seems to have incurred some "over-head" costs. For example, when I ran part 1, the size of the database was around 3 GB but when I added up all the rows from part 2, it was only about 2 GB. And there doesn't seem to be a predictable growth discrepancy as the table grows.

This size inconsistency reported by information_schema.TABLES and my estimated SUM query is making me delete more rows than I actually need to.

Some questions:

1. Am I even approaching this problem the correct way?
2. Am I way off on my calculations?
3. How can I determine the over-head costs?

Comment: Can you explain the reason for this procedure? On these days storage is so cheap  worring from some mb isnt really an issue. Anyway can you do a loop and delete one row each time until reach the desire size?

Comment: For my case, the database is actually quite expensive as it is on flash storage and fills up pretty quickly (~ 20 GB a day). Also, the piece I did not mention in my original post is that this database is part of a shard map so I need to do this routine for each of the shards (of which there are dozens).

Comment: I dont know what is a shard map. And what is the logic to choose what rows delete? In my case I got 4GB daily so just keep the last month and move the oldest day to another device everyday.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza By shard map, I was just trying to say that I have distributed multiple databases with these tables. The logic is basically: bytes_needed_to_delete = current_db_size - desired_db_size..Then I start adding up the size of each graph by my estimated calculation in part 2 until at least N number of bytes have been selected.

Comment: Please clarify via edit, not comment. Please act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I think you are taking the wrong approach by thinking about *deleting* records.  Deleting records is a very expensive operation.

Instead, you should be using *table partitioning*.  I'm not quite sure what the logic is, but all three tables can be partitioned on `g_id`.  Assuming this is assigned sequentially, you can create batches that approximate about one day's worth of new graphs.

You can then "delete" the rows by dropping old partitions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why deleting records is very expensive?

Comment: @vgbcell . . . Deleting records is expensive because the deletes are logged.  They also can cause partially filled data pages and indexes, which are detrimental to performance.

Answer (score 1):

Measuring a row size is quite messy in InnoDB.  I find that adding up the fields sizes (8 for `BIGINT`, and average length for a `VARCHAR`, etc), then *multiplying* by 2 or 3, will come close to the space needed for InnoDB.

Easier is to get the `Avg_row_size` from `SHOW TABLE STATUS` (or the equivalent in `information_schema.Tables`).

Looping through the rows won't get more accurate unless the row sizes vary quite wildly.  Even then, the "average" may be just as good.

Yes `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))` is an excellent way to speed up the delete.  You can, then, look at the partition sizes to see when it is time to delete the oldest partition.  This does, however, assume that you want to delete "all rows before some date".  More on such partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

You say your data is so big it is spread across multiple servers ("sharded")?  Please provide more details.  There are often techniques that can be applied to avoid such a rapid explosion of data.

If, for example, you are using `POINT` with latitude and longitude, this is about 4 times as big as storing the coordinates to *sufficient* precision without using `POINT`.

Comment: Regarding sharding, I have a simple key based horizontal sharding scheme distributed throughout a few dozen shards. Partitioning individual tables sounds interesting. But the thing is, the number of INSERTS into the shards vary unpredictable (some days it can be ~3GB other days it can be ~20 GB).

Comment: If you are inserting a thousand rows per second for long periods of time, you may need other tips.  For one:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table